# How to set active with multiple buttons

Tags: vue.js

I have three buttons that are generated in a div using v-for. When a button is clicked I want that specific button to get the active class and the one that was previously active to drop that class. I know how to do it with v-bind with one button. But I'm just not sure of the logic with three.

I thought about having three IsActiveButton1, IsActiveButton2 and IsActiveButton3. Then trying to bind the class to those. But since I'm using v-for I don't know how to tell it which IsActive to bind to. I also feel like there is a more efficient way.

I have played aroung with the [radio buttons toggle for vuejs](https://vuejsexamples.com/radio-toggle-buttons-for-vue/) however it very much lacks the styling abilities I need on the buttons.

```
<template>
    <div id="basemap_container">
        <button v-for="option in options" 
            :key="option.value" 
            :class="option.class"
            @click="UpdateBaseMap(option.value)"
        >{{option.text}}
        </button> 
        <button 
            id="collapse_basemap" 
            class="btn_group_basemap"
            @click="CollapseBaseMap()"
            >»
        </button>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

export default {
    name:"BaseMapToggle",
    data(){
        return{
         current_basemap: "streets",
         basemap_changer_active: true,
        options:[
                {text: "satellite", value:"satellite",class: "btn_group_basemap"},
                {text: "topo", value:"topo",class: "btn_group_basemap"},
                {text: "streets", value:"streets",class: "btn_group_basemap active"}
            ]
        }
    },
    methods:{
        UpdateBaseMap(value)
        {
            this.current_basemap = value;
            this.$store.commit('UpdateBaseMap',this.current_basemap);
        },

        CollapseBaseMap()
        {
            this.basemap_changer_active = !this.basemap_changer_active;
            const changer = document.querySelector("#collapse_basemap");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your `current_basemap` variable to do it:

```
<button v-for="option in options" 
  :key="option.value" 
  :class="option.class + `${option.value === current_basemap ? ' active ' : ''}`"
  @click="UpdateBaseMap(option.value)">
  {{option.text}}
</button>
```